# How to remove rules from a style in OpenOffice/LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice-writer, libreoffice

When creating a style in LibreOffice, you can "link" them to other rules so that they inherit the other rules styles and only modify specific properties. For example if the *default* style defines a font and *My Style* only adds an rule for italics, then changing the font of *default* will also change everything that is styled with *My Style*.

The usage of this is simple enough, as you make changes to a style it collects a list of modified properties. These properties are listed for reference in style dbx's Organizer tab:

[image: sceenshot of modify style dbx]

However, I cannot figure out how to remove them! Once a property in any of the tabs is touched, an override rule is added to the "style contains" section.

**How can I change a property back to a value of "inherited" or simply remove it from the *contains* list?** In the example above, say I want to set the value for indents so that they inherit from the linked style instead of use the 0 value shown?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally found some documentation that set my head straight on this.

Apparently the dialog box in question works on a tab-at-a-time basis. I tried the "Standard" and "Reset" buttons. Reset pretty clearly set things back to the way they were before I started making changes. What I didn't understand was how to use the "Standard" button.

In order to clear customized values and set them back to inherited, you have to select the tab of the items you want to clear, and hit the standard button. At that point everything in that tab is set to "inherit" and dropped from the "contains" list in the organizer tab. You cannot drop only one value from a tab, you have to clear them all. Once the tab is cleared of custom values you can customize any specific value again.

User Interface Fail!

Comment: This functionality is missing for page styles and list styles (at least in LO 3.4.3), there is only Reset button.

Comment: Do you have any idea by any chance if it is possible to **not inherit** from any style at all?  My problem is that i set a font in the Default style, and now if i create any style that inherits form Default, it will override any manually selected font (either with its own, or with the font defined in Default).  User experience fail indeed.

Comment: @Alexey I would ask your own stand alone question for that.