# How to just add conditional formatting to a cell without overwriting the cell's direct formatting

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have different cells with different background colors. Depending on a *Conditional Formatting* I'd like to add borders around some of these cells.

Applying the borders works but the cells' backgrounds are set to *No Fill* (as it is defined in the *Style* that's defined in the *Conditional Format*). I'd like to avoid  this, such applying *Conditional Formats* additive instead of alternative.

Comment: Related: [How to remove rules from a style in OpenOffice/LibreOffice?](https://superuser.com/q/292866)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different things after [Jim K's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1260896/516482) and found out that the key point seems to be that you never touch formats in the *Style* used in a *Conditional Format* if you don't want these formats to override your direct formattings.

Regarding background colors apparently there's a "null" color after creating the *Style* newly that cannot be set again once you selected *No fill* or a background color once.

Answer (score 1):

Create the style again from scratch.  The following steps worked for me:

1. Go to an unused, unformatted cell.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and set borders.
2. In the **Styles and Formatting** sidebar, click *New Style from Selection*.  Name it "Borders".
3. Enter 1 in cell A1 and then fill down to A4.
4. Select A1 through A4 and highlight yellow by pressing the **Background Color** toolbar button.
5. *Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage*.  Press *Add*.  "Cell value is," "greater than," 2.  Apply style "Borders".  Press OK.

The result:

[image: border on A3 and A4]